# copy and paste data in VBA without range

Tags: excel, vba

I have data like below

[image: click on image]

I want to fill last row with 0's. but the problem is every month number of rows will be changed. 
I want to write a code that automatically adds 0's in the last column based on column A or B or C or D number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something on your own... We usually help people improve their code, or correct things as does not work as expected.

Please, try the next code and confirm that it does what you need:

```
Sub FillZeroLastCol_Row()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the worksheet you need
  lastCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, lastCol), sh.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value = 0
  'if you also need zero on the last row, this can be done in this way:
  sh.Range(sh.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1), sh.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastCol)).Value = 0
End Sub
```

It can be made to check if you already did it, by checking the last column/row content...